# Looping Through FileReader onload Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I need to loop through all my inputs that are type file, and load it as a preview. My code so far:

```
var _i = 0;
function setImagesToPreview(){
  $("form#form-generate-mail input[type=file]").each(function(i){
    var input = $(this);
    _i = i;

    if (input.context['files'] && input.context['files'][0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $(document).find("div.modal-preview-mail img.image_placeholder:nth-child("+_i+")").attr('src', e.target.result);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.context['files'][0]);
    }
  });
}
```

The following code works, but for only 1 input. The reason for this, is that the variable 'i' that is acting as the counter, when it reaches the reader.onload, the variable is set to the final value.

ex: 5 inputs, the counter 'i' increments by 1 everytime, from 0 to 4, but once it gets to the reader.onload, it always displays 4 and never increments.

Any help will be usefull, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a context like so ....

```
  reader.onload = (function(index){
        return function (e) {
             $(document).find("div.modal-preview-mailimg.image_placeholder:nth-child("+index+")").attr('src', e.target.result);
      };
})(_i);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, that solved my problem, also i changed :nth-child to :eq, since it was an object it was returning.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the inner code with an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Thus you're creating a new execution context and the current state of `i` is saved in it.

Brief example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 50 * i);
    })(i);
}
```